# Comparing the similarity of ranked word lists with a reference standard

Tags: nonparametric, ranking, similarities

Imagine a scientific organisation wants to communicate the likelihood of particular events occurring. For consistency, the organisation decides to always draw from the same set of words, which it interprets as belonging to an ordinal scale:

1. Aways
2. Usually
3. Frequently
4. Often
5. Possibly
6. Rarely

I want to know to what extent people interpret these words in the same way as (a) each other; and (b) the scientific organisation. I also want to know if an alternative set of words improves interpretive consistency. The alternative words (phrases) are:

1. Extremely likely
2. Very likely
3. Likely
4. Unlikely
5. Very unlikely
6. Extremely unlikely

To address these questions, I plan to run a study in which participants each view all of the words sequentially, in a random order, and for each word, rate the likelihood of an event occurring on a scale from 0-100%. These ratings on a continuous scale can be converted to ranks to facilitate comparison with the organisation’s intended ranking (I do not ask participants to explicitly rank the words because in practice the organisation will only use one word from the list in each of its announcements).

I'm seeking advice on how to (1) compute the similarity of word ratings between people; (2) compute the similarity of people’s (implicit) ranking of the words with the organisations; (3) examine whether the alternative word set leads to higher consistency between people and for people compared to the intended ranking.

My reading so far suggests that for (1) I could measure the intraclass correlation (ICC) separately for each word and I could use Kendall’s W to measure consistency of people’s (implicit) rankings (converted from their continuous ratings) of all of the words.

For (2) If I was comparing two groups’ rankings, I think I could use a Mann-Whitney U test, but I wish to compare one group’s rankings to a reference standard, and I cannot find any information on how to do this. For (3), I can informally examine differences in ICC and Kendall’s W, but I think I need a formal statistical test to see if there’s a statistically significant difference in performance between the two word sets.

Bonus points for any advice on sample size planning, computing confidence intervals, and visualisation!

I’d be very grateful for any advice / pointers in the right direction.